# Mongoose saves data twice for one request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm relatively new with mongodb and express and I wish to save data which has been retrieved via an api call, to my database. For some reason my server saves the data twice (creates two documents with same details but different id's) for a single get request and I can't figure out why

```
const log = console.log;

const express = require('express')
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000
const movieServer = require('./movie-getter')
const { Movie } = require('./model/Movie')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/ConspireView', { useNewUrlParser: true});


const app = express()

app.get('/movie/:name/:year', (req, res) => {
    const name = req.params.name
    const year = req.params.year
    // let movieObject
    movieServer.getMovie(name, year).then((result) => {

        new Movie({
            name: result.title,
            year: result.release_date,
            poster: result.poster_path,
            banner: result.backdrop_path,
            numOfDiscussions: 0,
            numOfComments: 0,
            vote_average: 0
            // discussions: null
        }).save().then(result => {
            res.send(result)
        })        
    }).catch((error) => {
        log(error)
    }) 
})
```

Are there any syntactic errors here?

Comment: Coudn't see anything. You may try put a console.log first line in the controller function to be sure it is not called twice somehow.

Comment: And you're sure you're not calling the api twice, I assume?

Comment: No I'm 100% sure. It is just a normal api call which returns a JSON object

Comment: Try logging every request and see if you're actually calling it twice.  If you're calling it from chrome, you can also take a look at the network tab.